# Popup: Language support is incomplete – what packages does it want to install?

Tags: kde, language

I'm using Kubuntu 17.10. Always after login, the notification below pops up. When I click it, it asks for my password and wants to install or remove packages – but without telling me **what packages**. I already searched the internet but couldn't find a way to identify what packages are needed. The standard `apt upgrade` is not affecting this popup. What program is causing this popup, and how can I see which packages it wants to install?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The missing packages can be seen if installing the full language support in Terminal:

```
sudo apt install $(check-language-support)
```

Comment: Awesome! That seem to do the trick. So `check-language-support` is a bit misleading here, it should be named check-missing-language-package or at least give a short hint that it outputs missing files. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Grimm you're right about command name, even manpage says at beginning "check-language-support - returns the list of missing packages in order to provide a complete language environment".

Comment: After re-installing my KDE neon system with the current ISO image (based on Ubuntu 22.04), `check-language-support` was not available, but could be installed with `sudo apt install language-selector-common`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem with missing packages use `--ignore-missing`:

```
sudo apt-get -y install --ignore-missing $(check-language-support)
```